# Appending and Popping to and from different lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I am have written some code that pops 6 numbers based on their position in a list and then appends the actual numbers into a new list. All seemed well however, I have now noticed that on occasions the new list only includes 4 or 5 numbers rather than the six which is expected. I am baffled to why.

```
import random

numbers=list(range(1,60))
drawn=[]

for n in range (1,7):
     x=(random.randint(0,len(numbers)))
     if x in numbers:
          drawn.append(numbers[x])
          numbers.pop(x)
print("List with numbers popped")`enter code here`
print(numbers)

print("New list with random numbers appended") 
print(drawn)
```

Comment: Well for one, your random generator is picking from between 0 and 59.  `numbers` is 1 - 59.  So what happens when the random number is 0?

Comment: if the random value of `x` is the same as a previous iteration then `if x in numbers` will assert false

Answer (score 1):

`numbers` is filled with values [1, 60], however, `x` will be in the range [0, 60].

So sometimes `x` is 0, which is never present in `numbers`.